# GeckoFX 33.0: issue with permissionDBPDir not implemented?

Tags: c#, geckofx

I have a VS 2013 project which using GeckoFX 33.0 and XULrunner. It runs OK on my local machine. However after I deployed to the server, I got following exception:

**Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: permissionDBPDir**

Has anyone got any idea about this?

Thanks

Jing